# Login test using a select statement with the PDO function in PHP

Tags: php

This is the class definition (not sure if definition is the right word here, but it seems right).  I got almost all the code from http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69771-creating-a-simple-yet-secured-loginregistration-with-php5/ .  The insert part of it works fine.  Things I consider possible problems: using two connection bits of code in both the select and insert parts. The code makes sense to me except that it isn't working.  What am I missing?  I must have looked over it 20 times.

```
<?php

 class Users {
     public $username = null;
     public $password = null;
     public $salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";

     public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
         if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
         if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
     }

     public function storeFormValues($postvars) {
        //store the parameters
        $this->__construct($postvars); 
     }

     public function userLogin() {

         $success = false;

         try{
            $hostname = "localhost";
            $dbname = "customertest";
            $user = "user";
            $pw = "root";
            $connstr = "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname";
            $conn = new PDO($connstr,$user,$pw); 
            $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM employeetest WHERE login = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            if( $valid ) {
                $success = true;
            }

            $conn = null;
            return $success;
            } #end try
            catch (PDOException $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
             return $success;
            }
     }

     public function register() {
        $correct = false;
            try {
                $hostname = "localhost";
                $dbname = "customertest";
                $user = "user";
                $pw = "root";
                $connstr = "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname";
                $conn = new PDO($connstr,$user,$pw); 
                $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $sql = "INSERT INTO employeetest(login, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";

                $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
                $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->execute();
                return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
            }
            catch( PDOException $e ) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
     }

 }

?>



This is the table information:

mysql> describe employeetest;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| EmployeeID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| FirstName  | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| LastName   | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| telephone  | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Email      | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| login      | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.12 sec)

mysql>
```

The index.php (login page)

```
<?php 
    include_once("config.php");
?>

<?php if( !(isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) ) { ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Codecall Tutorials - Secured Login with php5</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <header id="head" >
            <p>Codecall tutorials User Login</p>
            <p><a href="/logintest/register.php"><span id="register">Register</span></a></p>
        </header>

        <div id="main-wrapper">
            <div id="login-wrapper">
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="usn">Username : </label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="username" />
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="passwd">Password : </label>
                            <input type="password" maxlength="30" required name="password" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="buttons">
                            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log me in" />
                            <input type="button" name="register" value="Register" onclick="location.href='register.php'" />
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>

<?php 
} else {
    $usr = new Users;
    $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

    if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
        echo "Welcome"; 
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 
    }
}
?>
```

The config.php

```
<?php
    //set off all error for security purposes
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //include the classes
    include_once( "class" . "/user.php" );


?>
```

This is the register.php

```
<?php 
    include_once("config.php");
?>

<?php if( !(isset( $_POST['register'] ) ) ) { ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Codecall Tutorials - Secured Login with php5</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header id="head" >
            <p>Codecall tutorials User Registration</p>
            <p><a href="/logintest/register.php"><span id="register">Register</span></a></p>
        </header>

        <div id="main-wrapper">
            <div id="register-wrapper">
                <form method="post">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="usn">Username : </label>
                            <input type="text" id="usn" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="username" />
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="passwd">Password : </label>
                            <input type="password" id="passwd" maxlength="30" required name="password" />
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="conpasswd">Confirm Password : </label>
                            <input type="password" id="conpasswd" maxlength="30" required name="conpassword" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="buttons">
                            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
                            <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='index.php'" />
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>

<?php 
} else {
    $usr = new Users;
    $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

    if( $_POST['password'] == $_POST['conpassword'] ) {
        echo $usr->register($_POST);    
    } else {
        echo "Password and Confirm password not match"; 
    }
}
?>
```

This is the information that is in the table to be searched for

aguy     dc9462f1ae80c4e2203201f9bd330d

when I registered, I used the password: abc.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this class

I optimised 2-3 things but I didn't catch any real issue with your old code

```
<?php

 class Users {
     private $username;
     private $password;
     private $salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";
     private $connection;

     public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
        if( empty($data['username']) || empty($data['password'])) {
            echo 'Missing Username or Password';
        }
        $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
        // do not strip anything from password if you are going to hash it , its just fine 
        // you don't need the plain password at all. So just hash it here..
        $this->password = $this->hashPassword($data['password']);
     }

     private function hashPassword($pass)
     {
        return hash("sha256", $pass . $this->salt);
     }

     public function storeFormValues($postvars) {
        //store the parameters
        # This is not possible ->__construct() .. instead you have to make new instance
//        $this->__construct($postvars); 
     }

     private function getConnection()
     {
        if(empty($this->connection)){
            $hostname = "localhost";
            $dbname = "customertest";
            $user = "user";
            $pw = "root";
            $connstr = "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname";
            $this->connection = new PDO($connstr,$user,$pw); 
            $this->connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }
        return $this->connection;
     }

     public function userLogin() {
         try{
            $sql = "SELECT login FROM employeetest WHERE login = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";

            $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", $this->password, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt->fetchColumn();
            } #end try
            catch (PDOException $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
             return FALSE;
            }
     }

     public function register() {
        try {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO employeetest (login, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";

            $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", $this->password, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
        }
        catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: if this->__construct($postvars); isn't possible, why are the form values being passed to the insert query? – 

also why did you use $pass instead of $password in the hash function?

Oh, it's a parameter, sorry

Comment: Will this work for the new instance?  

$newInstance = new Users;
$newInstance->construct($postvars);

I'm getting undefined index for the variables password and username

Comment: When I copied and pasted your code I got: Missing Username or Password
Notice: Undefined index: username in E:\xampp\htdocs\logintest\class\user.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: password in E:\xampp\htdocs\logintest\class\user.php on line 16
Incorrect Username/Password

Probably because I don't know how to create a new instance properly.

Comment: new instance is just callin new class.. 
$class = new Users($dataparams);  data params is your array with username and password.